# Run process and notify when finish

Tags: go

Im using the following code which **works fine**,
Now I want to **notify** to when the process finish

I try to add another function after the `wait` and it doesn't helps

I need to know when **all the commands are finished successfully** and send message to other package, how can I do it ? 
or call to **other function** just when the `Invoke` function **done all the execution**

```
 cmdParams := [][]string{
        {filepath.Join(dir, path), "npm", "install"},
        {filepath.Join(pdir, n.path), "gulp"},
    }

func Invoke(cmdParams [][]string) error {
    for _, cp := range cmdParams {
        log.Printf("Starting %s in folder %s...", cp[1:], cp[0])
        cmd := exec.Command(cp[1], cp[2:]...)
        cmd.Dir = cp[0]

        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s cmd.StdoutPipe() error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
            return
        }
        // Start command:
        if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("%s start error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
            return
        }

        // Stream command output:
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
        scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Print(scanner.Text())
        }
        if scanner.Err() != nil {
            log.Printf("Reading %s stdout error: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
            return
        }

        // Get execution success or failure:
        if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error running %s: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
            return
        }
        log.Printf("Finished %s", cp[1:])
    }
```

Comment: You're not doing this in parallel, so... when `Invoke` finishes, all the commands have finished. What about this are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: func declaration for Invoke says it returns error but your return statements don't